# UITableView - Select nearest row after row deletion

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uisplitviewcontroller

like build in apple notes app, after you swipe to delete the selected row, it will select the nearest available row automatically.

The logic should be:

> if row count > 0 then
>   if deleted_row == last row then
>   select deleted_row_index-1 row
>   else
>   select deleted_row_index+1 row
>   end
>   end

i have try to implement the above logic in the *commitEditingStyle* event, but the selection fail.
the *selectRowAtIndexPath* logic just don't work in this event, if i apply it in a button, it works.

any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to solve this is to use the method `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`.

From within the `tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:` you can:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPathToSelect = ...
[self performSelector:@selector(selectRowAtIndexPath:) 
           withObject:indexPathToSelect
               afterDelay:0];
```

Then define the `selectRowAtIndexPath:` method in your view controller

```
- (void)selectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath 
                              animated:YES 
                        scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you delete a row, you should have its indexPath. Then you call the method

`(void)scrollToRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath atScrollPosition:(UITableViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition animated:(BOOL)animated`

For indexPath you can set the new indexPath, by increasing or decreasing the indexPath.row by 1.

scrollPosition sets whether the tableView scrolls up or down, and animated should be clear.

After all, you manually select that UITableViewCell.

```
[cell setSelected:YES];
```